# Как конвертировать HttpClient.GetAsync("ссылка на картинку") в BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, uwp

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: Хороший вопрос ) Вы хотя бы кусок вашего кода привели.

Comment: ой совсем забыл минутку

Answer (score 1):

Можно сразу ссылку подставить в `BitmapImage`, он сам загрузит картинку.

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ссылка на картинку"));
```

Comment: если бы так получилось я бы не спрашивал

Comment: @Сергей а что Вы иммено делали?  у мнея все заработало и на форме показывается картинка. А Вы пытались этот `BitmapImage` отобразить на форме?

Comment: WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://pp.userapi.com/c625127/v625127790/2a520/DjJKxD7QOYA.jpg"); //ссылка на картинку
client.DownloadFile(uri, "picture.jpg"))

Comment: В XAML-e в качестве источника картинки можно поставить урл и всё само скачивается, ничего делать не надо.